# UIButton not showing in UIView using Swift

Tags: iphone, xcode, swift, uibutton, ios8

I am trying to create a view that stays at the bottom of the screen. The UIView works correctly and displays. I am trying to place a UIButton the size of the UIView in it, but the button just will not show. I placed this code in the Swift Playground and it worked! When I run it in the iOS simulator in my app the UIView displays but not the button. I have no idea what is going on.

```
var ySize = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.height - 40
let searchView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: ySize, width: self.view.bounds.width, height: 40))
searchView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0/255.0, green: 71/255.0, blue: 133/255.0, alpha: 1)

let searchButton: UIButton = UIButton.buttonWithType(.System) as UIButton
searchButton.frame = searchView.frame
searchButton.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
searchButton.setTitle("Search Transactions", forState: .Normal)

searchView.addSubview(searchButton)

self.navigationController?.view.addSubview(searchView)
```

Comment: Try playing around with the `center` property of the `searchButton` and see. My guess is your button is off screen.

Comment: I just tired it and still no luck. If I add a UILabel it works. Just the button does not work. I am so confused!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got it. I was using the frame and not the bounds. Using the frame would place it incorrectly, but using the bounds made it work.

```
searchButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, recentView.bounds.width, recentView.bounds.height)
```

Comment: Exactly where I was getting at ;-) Glad it worked out.

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 3.x+**

```
searchButton.frame = CGRect.init(x: 0.0, y:0.0, width:200.0, height:50.0)
```